# Font awesome Icon HTML in widgets disappear on save

Tags: widgets, widget-text, icon

I've created a Text widget and put font-awesome icon HTML in editor Text Mode `<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>` but toggling to Visual mode makes the code disappears though I can see it working on Frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that WordPress removes empty tags from the editor. Try adding in a non-breaking space - Font Awesome should remove it so you shouldn't see any noticeable difference:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook">&nbsp;</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong syntax.

True syntax is `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`.
Also verify that you have added font-awesome in your theme and function file.

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on the Font Awesome version. Font Awesome 5 uses `fab` instead of `fa` to display brands.

Answer (score 0):

@Harsh - The original poster was using the syntax from Font Awesome 5, where different prefixes are used based on whether it is a brand (fab prefix), solid (fas prefix), regular (far prefix) and light (fal prefix).

Also, I found that the `"&nbsp;"` did resolve disappearing icon the issue for me.